# Don't find MLO and img files after building u-boot for raspberrypi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, bootloader, u-boot

i'm working on building U-Boot boot loader for raspberry pi 4. i have followed all the documentation instructions and  building has finished well, but the results files are the following

```
u-boot
u-boot.bin
u-boot.cfg
u-boot.cfg.configs
u-boot.lds
u-boot.map
u-boot-nodtb.bin
u-boot.srec
u-boot.sym
```

i can't find MLO or u-boot.img to put them on the SD card.
so the question is; is there any specific or custom configurations should i take before building to generate MLO and img files ?
Does this happend because the new design of rpi4, which has EEPROM that alreadey contains the SPL and no need for MLO and img files ?
could any one give me some tips?

also i have used `rpi_4_defconfig` from `uboot/configs`, and generate custom toolchain for raspberrypi 4 using cross-ng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MLO` file is specific to Texas Instruments (TI) SoCs and their ROM.  What you'll want to do in the case of a Raspberry Pi 4 is to copy `u-boot.bin` to `kernel8.img` and that will cause the Pi's firmware to load U-Boot.